# Segmentation fault in my assembly program

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I am getting a segmentation fault from this simple starting program.

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 and `kdbg` for debugging. Affter reaching starting `__int 80h__`, it stops moving to the next line.

```
section .bss    ; section containing uninitialized data

BUFFLEN equ 1024    ; length of buffer
Buff: resb BUFFLEN  ; text buffer itself

section .data   ; section containing initialzed data
section .text   ; secttion containing code

global _start   ; linker needs to find the entry point!

_start:
  nop       ; this no-op keeps gdb happy

  ; read buffer full of text form stdin:
read:
    mov eax, 3  ; specify sys_read call
    mov ebx, 0  ; specify file descriptor 0 : standard input
    mov ecx, Buff ; pass offset of the buffer to read to 
    mov edx, BUFFLEN    ;  pass number of bytes to be read at one pass
    int 80h     ; call sys_read to fill the buffer
    mov esi,eax     ; copy sys_read return value for safekeeping
    cmp eax, 0   ; if eax = 0 , sys_read reached EOF on stdin
    je Done     ; jump if Equal ( to o, form compare)


; set up the register for the process buffer step: 
    mov ecx, esi    ; place the number of bytes read into ecx
    mov ebp, Buff   ; pace address of buffer into ebp
    dec ebp         ; adjust the count to offset

; go through the buffer and cnvert lowercase to uppercase characters:
Scan:
    cmp byte [ebp+ecx], 61h     ; test input char agaisnst lowercase 'a'
    jb Next         ; if Below 'a'  in ASCII, not lowercase
    cmp byte [ebp+ecx], 7Ah     ; test against lowercase 'z'
    ja Next

    sub byte [ebx+ecx], 20h ; subtract 20h to give uppercase..

Next:
    dec ecx ; Decrement counter
    jnz Scan    ; if characters reamin, loop back

; Write the buffer full of processed text to stdout:
Write:
    mov eax,4   ; Specify sys_write call
    mov ebx, 1  ; Specify file descriptor 1 : stdout
    mov ecx, Buff   ; pass the offset of the buffer
    mov edx, esi ; pass the # of bytes of data in the buffer
    int 80h     ; make sys_write kernel call
    jmp read    ; loop back and load another buffer full

Done:
    mov eax, 1  ; Code for Exit sys_call
    mov ebx, 0  ; return code of Zero
    int 80h
```

I used these commands:

```
nasm -f elf -g -F stabs uppercaser1.asm
ld -m elf_i386 -o uppercaser1 uppercaser1.o
./uppercaser < inputflie
```

Comment: Do you really get a segmentation fault or does it not continue (i.e. it looks as if it's hanging)? That's a huge difference.

Comment: I recommend you run your code through a debugger. it should tell you where in your code this crashes. use `gdb ./uppercaser1` for example you do `sub byte [ebx+ecx], 20h` .I think you mean to use `sub byte [ebp+ecx], 20h` ?

Comment: Did you try running without directing the external file (i.e., ./uppercaser < inputflie)? Never mind, still got Segmentation fault

Comment: The seg fault occurs upon entering lower case characters following the read syscall. I can enter upper case, numbers, and other chars; which does result in a segfault.  I have working copy of almost the same code on my computer. Is this homework or from the book Assembly Language Step-by-Step: Programming with Linux 3rd Edition?

Comment: thanks man it should be ebp  , but why does it stops in kdbg while it executes first int 80h  @MichaelPetch

Comment: it was getting stopped but not segmentation fault @PMF

Comment: That is probably a problem with kdbg and how it redirects. If you run your program from the command line and it works it is almost certainly how kdbg is handling standard in and output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is generally public so I am posting with that in mind.

You should use the code as a guide to understanding what may be wrong in your code; however, it does not conform to any coding standard so it is pointless just to copy and paste and turn it in as an assignment; assuming that is the case.

You will never increase your assembly programming skills by merely doing a copy/paste.

lsb_release -a
...
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

nasm -f elf32 -g uppercase1.s -o uppercase1.o && ld -m elf_i386 uppercase1.o -o uppercase1

```
section .bss
        Buff resb 1

section .data

section .text
        global _start
_start:
        nop

Read:
        mov eax, 3              ; read syscall
        mov ebx, 0              ; stdin
        mov ecx, Buff           ; pass address of the buffer to read to
        mov edx, 1              ; read one char or one byte
        int 0x80                ;

        cmp eax, 0              ; if syscall returns returns 0
        je Exit                 ;

        cmp byte [Buff], 0x61   ; lower case a
        jb Write                ; jump if byte is below a in ASCII chart
        cmp byte [Buff], 0x7a   ; lower case z
        ja Write                ; jump if byte is above z in ASCII chart

        sub byte [Buff], 0x20   ; changes the value in the buffer to an uppercase char


Write:
        mov eax, 4              ; write syscall
        mov ebx, 1              ; stdout
        mov ecx, Buff           ; what to print
        mov edx, 1              ; length is one byte - each char is a byte
        int 0x80
        jmp Read                ; go back to Read

Exit:
        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 0x80
```

Sample output:

```
david@ubuntuserver00A:~/asm$ ./uppercase1  < uppercase1.s
SECTION .BSS
        BUFF RESB 1

SECTION .DATA

SECTION .TEXT
        GLOBAL _START
_START:
        NOP

READ:
        MOV EAX, 3              ; READ SYSCALL
        MOV EBX, 0              ; STDIN
        MOV ECX, BUFF           ; PASS ADDRESS OF THE BUFFER TO READ TO
        MOV EDX, 1              ; READ ONE CHAR OR ONE BYTE
        INT 0X80                ;

        CMP EAX, 0              ; IF SYSCALL RETURNS RETURNS 0
        JE EXIT                 ;

        CMP BYTE [BUFF], 0X61   ; LOWER CASE A
        JB WRITE                ; JUMP IF BYTE IS BELOW A IN ASCII CHART
        CMP BYTE [BUFF], 0X7A   ; LOWER CASE Z
        JA WRITE                ; JUMP IF BYTE IS ABOVE Z IN ASCII CHART

        SUB BYTE [BUFF], 0X20   ; CHANGES THE VALUE IN THE BUFFER TO AN UPPERCASE CHAR


WRITE:
        MOV EAX, 4              ; WRITE SYSCALL
        MOV EBX, 1              ; STDOUT
        MOV ECX, BUFF           ; WHAT TO PRINT
        MOV EDX, 1              ; LENGTH IS ONE BYTE - EACH CHAR IS A BYTE
        INT 0X80
        JMP READ                ; GO BACK TO READ

EXIT:
        MOV EAX, 1
        MOV EBX, 0
        INT 0X80
```